# How to deploy Socket.io and SvelteKit web app to Vercel?

Tags: typescript, express, socket.io, vercel, sveltekit

I am working on a .io-style multiplayer game that uses Socket.io and SvelteKit. When hosting the project locally with a development server, everything works fine, but when I deploy to [Vercel](https://natelu.vercel.app/), it logs `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`.

Here is my current express server.ts (non-functional)

```
import http from "HTTP";
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
// Gives error: An import path cannot end with a '.ts' extension.
import injectSocketIO from "src/lib/socket-handler.ts";
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

injectSocketIO(server)

app.use(handler);

// Should I change something here?
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Running on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

I am able to run a development server locally using the vite plugin like so:

```
import injectSocketIO from "./src/lib/socket-handler";

plugins: [sveltekit(), {
    name: "sveltekit-socket-io",
    configureServer(server) {
        injectSocketIO(server.httpServer);
    },
}],
```

I tried following the steps outlined [here](https://linu.us/live-chat-with-sveltekit-and-socketio#heading-make-it-work-in-production), but I am using `socket-handler.ts` instead of `socket-handler.js` and am unfamiliar with how to set a startup script to run with Vercel. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still looking for a better way, but I fixed the same problem by taking the Express server outside of the Svelte `src` directory.

My code is the same as yours, only importing `socket-handler.js` from the root directory:

```
// server.js
import express from 'express'
import injectSocketIO from './socket-handler.js'
import { handler } from './build/handler.js'

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)

// Inject SocketIO
injectSocketIO(server)

// SvelteKit handlers
app.use(handler)

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Running on http://localhost:3000')
})
```

Now run `npm run build && node server.js` to build the Svelte app and then start the Express server.

This [tutorial](https://joyofcode.xyz/using-websockets-with-sveltekit) put me on to that solution. You basically run a standard Express server, add socket.io and let SvelteKit handle the rest using Express middleware.